# Automatically set app instance in Truffle console

Tags: truffle

Is there a way to load the `truffle console` with the following variables without having to do manual type-ins on every test?

```
let app = await MyContract.deployed();
let accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

Excuse the naivety, starting out with Solidity/Truffle and asking the basic questions that don't seem to be answered (probably because they're not possible).

Comment: Just wondering why don't you do your tests the usual way with ```truffle test```? You write your tests for each contract method there and whenever smart contract change is done you run the tests to check if everything is ok.

Comment: Thanks, will look into tests to see how it might help here. It would be great if `truffle console` stored commands in memory after exiting though!